# help need to start developing simple jigsaw puzzle game

Tags: iphone

i am doing a simple  game like puzzle.

for that there is 9-patch image in android.

similarly is there is any facility in iphone.

i am doing manually  for this as fallows.

```
 UIImage* whole = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bull.jpg"]; //I know this image is 300x300

     int partId = 0;
     for (int x=0; x<=200; x+=100) {
         for(int y=0; y<=200; y+=100) {
             CGImageRef cgImg = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(whole.CGImage, CGRectMake(x, y, 100, 100));
             UIImage* part = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImg];
            if (partId == 0 ) {
                photo.image = part;

            }
             if (partId == 1 ) {
                 photo1.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 2 ) {
                 photo2.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 3 ) {
                 photo3.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 4 ) {
                 photo4.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 5 ) {
                 photo5.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 6 ) {
                 photo6.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 7 ) {
                 photo7.image = part;

             }
             if (partId == 8 ) {
                 photo8.image = part;

             }



             partId++;
         }
     }
```

here photo,photo1,...,photo8 are image views
 but this is not good.

while dragging images one images comes under the another images.

can any one please suggest better way to start my puzzle game.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: First give some details (instead of posting lot of code) about how you are using nine patch image for your puzzle. Also the answer posted is what you are looking for. Its the equivalent of nine patch for iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should probably check out the UIImage documentation:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

In particular, this method:

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

iOS doesn't have a '9-patch' image, in the sense that a 9-patch defines the stretchable sections within the image itself. Instead, you define the stretchable parts of the image in code (leftCapWidth and topCapHeight respectively).

I'm not quite sure how that helps you with your game, but since your question was 'is there something similar to 9-patch' on iOS, I hope this answer suffices!

Comment: hey i did n't get how to use it can u please suggest some tutorial or code regarding this